# How to check if a string contains a space in Robot Framework with Should Contain keyword

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to just check that I got back something in a string using `Should Contain`

[image]

I can't figure out why there is no `" "` in `'\r \r'`

Any ideas what I am missing?

```
>>> x='\r \r'
>>> " " in x
True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use  `" "` as an argument in Robot, it will be three chars : quotes, space, quote. If you want to use only space, then you should use ${SPACE} variable :

```
Should Contain  ${result}  ${SPACE}
```

See ["handling spaces"](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#rules-for-parsing-the-data) section of the documentation.